# Create a table for N, Min/Max, SD, Mean, and Median in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm very new to **R**, so please bear with me on this basic question.
I have a dataset, DATA, that I created using the data.table package. I created 200 random numbers between 0 and 1, then did that 10000 times, finally creating a data table for with descriptive statistics for each iteration.  My code for it looked like this:

```
rndm<-runif(200, min=0, max=1)
reps <- data.table(x=runif(200*10000),iter=rep(1:200,each=10000))
DATA <- reps[,list(mean=mean(rndm),median=median(rndm),sd=sd(rndm),min=min(rndm),
max=max(rndm)),by=iter]
```

The data looks something like this:

```
    Mean    Median     SD    Min    Max
1   0.521    0.499   0.287  0.010  0.998
2   0.511    0.502   0.290  0.009  0.996
.    ...     ...
```

etc.

What I want to do is create a table that finds N, mean, median, standard deviation, minimum, and maximum **of the accumulated sample means** (not of each column like above). I need the output to look something like this:

```
   N     Mean   Median    SD    Min    Max
 10000  .502     .499    .280  .002   .999
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This might be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323053/code-for-monte-carlo-simulation-generate-samples-of-given-size-in-r/16323583#16323583

Comment: Ha! I think this guy is in my class.

Comment: I still don't understand how to get the table in the above format, which is what I'm really trying to accomplish. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Kara - I don't quite understand what you want - just `DATA[, list(mean(mean), median(median), ...)]` or smth else?

Comment: For basic stats about the mean: `summary(DATA$mean)`. That gives mean/median/min/max of your sample means.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not being clear. I need to generate a table that describes the total N, mean, median, sd, min, and max of the MEAN variable from the DATA set. I know how to make a regular table, and even how to nest summary into a table, but nothing I know how to do generates a table that looks like the table above.

Comment: @Frank But how do I include the total N and the standard deviation? And how do I get it to output like above?

Comment: I think to make it look exactly like that, you may have to do it by hand: `c(N=length(summary$mean),Mean=mean(summary$mean))`. By doing `N=...`, you'll put the label on top. All six of the things you're looking for are standard R functions, `?sd`, etc.

Comment: That worked! Duh, why didn't I think of that?! Thank you so much Frank!!

Comment: `reps[, as.list(c(N=.N, summary(x)))]` is what you're looking for, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also define a function. This approach allows you to make the same table for a different variable.

```
summaryfun <- function(x)list(N=length(x),Mean=mean(x),Median=median(x),SD=sd(x),Min=min(x),Max=max(x))
DATA[,summaryfun(mean)]
```

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, you're calculating functions in the list separately for every item different `iter`. But if you want the aggregate stats, just remove the `by` clause, and your functions will run once, over the whole of the dataset. Then add an item to give `N` - making use of the `.N` variable provided by data.table.

```
DATA <- reps[, list(N=.N, mean=mean(rndm), median=median(rndm), 
                    sd=sd(rndm), min=min(rndm), max=max(rndm))]
```