# How should you use the data.table 'by' parameter to create multiple columns of data?

Tags: r, data.table

I am creating quite a few columns using the by parameter of data.table.  Here is some example data that I'll use to illustrate the issue.

```
> dt <- data.table(x=runif(10), group=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))
> dt
            x group
 1: 0.0488727     1
 2: 0.3087102     1
 3: 0.8107115     1
 4: 0.7368206     1
 5: 0.2941478     1
 6: 0.5221693     2
 7: 0.2505612     2
 8: 0.2730681     2
 9: 0.2098595     2
10: 0.4512163     2
```

I want to make some summary statistics for each group of data using the "by" parameter.  One option is to assign them all to columns within `dt`:

```
> dt[, max:=max(x), by=group]
> dt[, min:=min(x), by=group]
> dt[, mean:=mean(x), by=group]
> dt[, median:=median(x), by=group]
> dt
            x group       max       min      mean    median
 1: 0.0488727     1 0.8107115 0.0488727 0.4398526 0.3087102
 2: 0.3087102     1 0.8107115 0.0488727 0.4398526 0.3087102
 3: 0.8107115     1 0.8107115 0.0488727 0.4398526 0.3087102
 4: 0.7368206     1 0.8107115 0.0488727 0.4398526 0.3087102
 5: 0.2941478     1 0.8107115 0.0488727 0.4398526 0.3087102
 6: 0.5221693     2 0.5221693 0.2098595 0.3413749 0.2730681
 7: 0.2505612     2 0.5221693 0.2098595 0.3413749 0.2730681
 8: 0.2730681     2 0.5221693 0.2098595 0.3413749 0.2730681
 9: 0.2098595     2 0.5221693 0.2098595 0.3413749 0.2730681
10: 0.4512163     2 0.5221693 0.2098595 0.3413749 0.2730681
```

This is bad because you create columns with a lot of unnecessarily repeated elements.  I don't know of a reasonable way to collapse that data.table down.

The alternative is to put each result into a separate data.table and then merge them together:

```
> a<-dt[, max(x), by=group]
> b<-dt[, min(x), by=group]
> c<-dt[, mean(x), by=group]
> d<-dt[, median(x), by=group]
> setnames(a, "V1", "max")
> setnames(b, "V1", "min")
> setnames(c, "V1", "mean")
> setnames(d, "V1", "median")
> setkeyv(a, "group")
> setkeyv(b, "group")
> setkeyv(c, "group")
> setkeyv(d, "group")
> dt.summary.stats -> a[b][c][d]
> dt.summary.stats
   group       max       min      mean    median
1:     1 0.8107115 0.0488727 0.4398526 0.3087102
2:     2 0.5221693 0.2098595 0.3413749 0.2730681
```

dt.summary.stats contains the results I want, but this feels like a very asinine way of getting there.  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: you can try ddply in plyr package. ddply(dt, .(group), summarize, max = max(x), min = min(x), mean = mean(x), median = median(x))

Comment: Somewhat similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342261/create-a-table-for-n-min-max-sd-mean-and-median-in-r/16342881#16342881

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
dt[, list(max = max(x), min = min(x), mean = mean(x), median = median(x)),
     by = group]
#   group       max        min      mean    median
#1:     1 0.8185661 0.02120035 0.3277341 0.1721039
#2:     2 0.9243562 0.28941571 0.6137555 0.5826848
```

Or just use `summary`:

```
dt[, as.list(summary(x)), by = group]
#   group   Min. 1st Qu. Median   Mean 3rd Qu.   Max.
#1:     1 0.0212  0.1517 0.1721 0.3277  0.4751 0.8186
#2:     2 0.2894  0.4243 0.5827 0.6138  0.8480 0.9244
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that will let you use arbitrary summary functions

```
summary_fun <- function(.fun,.x,...) {
  .FUN = match.fun(.fun)
  r <- .FUN(.x,...)
}


summary_list <- function(funs,.x,...){
  r <- lapply(funs, summary_fun,.x=.x,...)
  setattr(r,'names',funs)
}


dt[,summary_list(c('mean','median','min','max'),.x=x,na.rm=TRUE),by=group]
#   group   mean median     min    max
# 1     1 0.5128 0.5417 0.05253 0.8978
# 2     2 0.5721 0.5828  0.3817 0.7549
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
> dt[, list(max = max(x), min = min(x), mean = mean(x), median = median(x)), by = group]
   group       max         min      mean    median
1:     1 0.9287178 0.337082563 0.6513641 0.6619631
2:     2 0.6329924 0.001502332 0.4282116 0.4998901
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

`aggregate(dt$x, by=list(dt$group), summary)`