# aggregate means and keep N

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to `aggregate` a dataset, but I want to also keep the number of observations. So what I have is similar to this:

```
aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length, by=list(iris$Species), FUN=mean)
```

But that returns an object like so:

```
 Group.1     x
1     setosa 5.006
2 versicolor 5.936
3  virginica 6.588
```

when what I want is that AND the number  of observations (rows) in each group (in a separate column)

Comment: Ah ha! I knew that there was a simple way to do it. Just couldn't think of it! Thanks, @Frank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trial and error revealed that this works:

```
FUN = function(x) c(m = mean(x), n = length(x))
```

There are other ways to do this in packages like dplyr and data.table.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @PierreLafortune

Answer (score 3):

dplyr and hadley ftw

```
grp <- group_by(iris, Species)
summarise(grp, avg = mean(Sepal.Length), n =n ())

Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
     Species   avg  n
1     setosa 5.006 50
2 versicolor 5.936 50
3  virginica 6.588 50
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't use dplyr much, but my understanding is that you can't summarize groups with a user-written function, right? I'm actually using a function I wrote, rather than `mean`.

Comment: You use summarise() with aggregate functions, which take a vector of values, and return a single number. As long as you fill that category you'll be ok.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. That makes sense. Things I had read elsewhere seemed to indicate that summarise only took certain pre-defined functions. This must be what they were referencing.

Comment: @Alex Obligatory plug for data.table http://stackoverflow.com/q/16342261/1191259 The OP unfortunately named a column "mean", which makes it a little confusing. That allows for a fun with vector return instead of scalar/single-value.